# Linux shell string substitution with multiple occurrences

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell

When I use the shell string substitution mechanism, only the first occurrence is replaced.

For instance, If I try to replace the substring `@folder` with substring `mypod` in the string:

`hostname | grep @folder && cat /etc/hosts | grep @folder`

I get

`hostname | grep mypod && cat /etc/hosts | grep @folder`

Here is what I tried:

```
root@mypod:/# export var="hostname | grep @folder && cat /etc/hosts | grep @folder"
root@mypod:/# echo $var                                                            
hostname | grep @folder && cat /etc/hosts | grep @folder
root@mypod:/# var2=${var/@folder/mypod}
root@mypod:/# echo $var2
hostname | grep mypod && cat /etc/hosts | grep @folder
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`${var/@folder/mypod}` should be `${var//@folder/mypod}`

If you are using bash, [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html) you have a guide on variables expansion you might find useful.

Comment: Thx but I dont understand why I should escape @. It already works this way

Comment: `//@` this is not an escaping this is the replacement syntax to replace ALL instances and this `/@` will replace only the FIRST

Comment: Thx again Miguel. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From the bash man-page, section ***Parameter Expansion***: *the longest match of pattern against its value is replaced*. It does not say "all matches are replaced"

Comment: Ok. Concretely, Can I make it replace all instances or is it impossible?

Comment: @Abdelghani : From what I know, with parameter expansion, only by looping over the parameter and apply the replacement again and again, until it does not change anymore. This is something you could put into a function. However, Miguel has provided in his answer a solution, which maybe works (it's new to me too). Another possibilitiy is to use an external tool such as `sed`, but this means that you create a child process. Depending on your concrete application, this might be considered acceptable or too expensive.